# er errors Given when installing libssh2-php

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, php, lamp, sendmail

Hi I'm trying to install a mail server on my ubuntu 13.10 machine, I have LAMP server installed, and works great, I want for my computer to be able to send emails (working as a server) so I decided to install sendmail

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

however It gave me an error when trying to access libssh2-php I removed libssh2-php, and tried to reinstall, but it gives me the following error

```
$sudo apt-get install libssh2-php
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssh2-php
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/28,6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 121 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libssh2-php.
(Reading database ... 291773 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libssh2-php (from .../libssh2-php_0.11.3-0.1build2_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up libssh2-php (0.11.3-0.1build2) ...
```

Creating config file /etc/php5/conf.d/ssh2.ini with new version
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/etc/php5/conf.d/ssh2.ini’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing libssh2-php (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssh2-php
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I'm not shure if y should create the /etc/php5/conf.d/ssh2.ini directory its unable to find...

however I located the conf.d directory on my machine, its located at

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d
```

I thought about moving the directory, but I'm afraid other things will stop working, because they run on /etc/php5/cli/conf.d

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` returns:

```
Setting up libssh2-php (0.11.3-0.1build2) ...
Creating config file /etc/php5/conf.d/ssh2.ini with new version
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/etc/php5/conf.d/ssh2.ini’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing libssh2-php (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing: libssh2-php
```

Can anybody helpme ??

tx in advance

Comment: What do you get if you do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: Try to reinstall `php5` package.

Answer (score -2):

As a work around:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/php5/conf.d/ 
sudo apt-get install libssh2-php
```